# file dialog to choose image path and use python file .py to run using that path

Tags: python

I wrote a python code to take a specific image (using image path) and do object/face detection on it. like this

```
python image_face_and_detect.py --weights ./checkpoints/custom-416 --size 416 --model yolov4 --images ./data/images/Test.jpg
```

Right now to execute the file I have to specify the image path, however, I want a code to open file dialog to allow me to choose the image and then run the (image_face_and_detect.py)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file dialogs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.filedialog) from the `tkinter` module. To run the command in a terminal, you can use the [`system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) function from the `os` module:

```py
from os import system
from tkinter import filedialog

filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
command = f"python image_face_and_detect.py --weights ./checkpoints/custom-416 --size 416 --model yolov4 --images {filename}"
system(command)
```

Comment: but how can I input the file path and execute the python file at the same time? 
e.g, I want the path of the selected file to be printed after {-- images} in the code above.

Comment: You can access the file name with `file.name`. Sorry if I understood you incorrectly, but you want to run the python script *after* you select the file?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: @AbdulazizAlshamsi Ok, i edited the answer.